# How do I make my reddit bot work at specified intervals?

Tags: python, time, reddit, praw

Essentially, I've written a program for a reddit bot designed to list down certain apsects of a reddit post, such as the title or poster, as long as they fit a certain criteria. I want it to be able to automatically run once every hour. I also want it to be able to make a post once every 7 days. Could someone share code for these please?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import base64
import praw

#Enter your correct Reddit information into the variable below

userAgent = 'RRBot-Beta'
cID = 'Enter your so and so'
cSC = 'Enter your secret'
userN = 'Enter your Reddit username'
userP = 'Enter your Reddit password'
unfilled_post_URL = [""]
unfilled_post_url_B64 = [""]
submission_title_and_poster = {}
filled_requests = 0
unfilled_requests = 0
requests = 0
reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent,
                     client_id=cID,
                     client_secret=cSC,
                     username=userN,
                     password=userP)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('riprequestsnew')  #any subreddit you want to monitor

title_keywords = {'requests', 'request'}  #makes a set of keywords to find in subreddits
comment_keyword = "share"

for submission in subreddit:
    lowercase_title = submission.title.lower()  #makes the post title lowercase so we can compare our keywords with it.
    for title_keyword in title_keywords:  #goes through our keywords
        if title_keyword in lowercase_title:  #if one of our keywords matches a title in the subreddit
            requests = requests + 1 #tracks the number of requests

for post in requests:
    comments = subreddit.submission.comment.lower() #makes the comment text lowercase
    if comment_keyword in comments: #checks the comment text for our keyword
        filled_requests += 1 #if someone has shared something, this post will be marked as filled
    elif comment_keyword not in comments: #if no one has shared anything, the post url will be added to a list
        submission_title_and_poster.update({subreddit.submission.title: subreddit.submission.name})
        unfilled_post_URL.append(subreddit.submission.url)
        for url in unfilled_post_URL:  #B64 encodes each url and adds it to a new list
            text = open(url, "rb")
            text_read = text.read()
            url_encoded = base64.encodestring(text_read)
            unfilled_post_url_B64.append(url_encoded)
        unfilled_requests += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Schedule (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) seemed to be what you need.

You will have to install their Python library:

```
pip install schedule
```

then modify the sample script :

```
import schedule
import time

def job():

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

With your own function in job() and use the needed call for your timing.

Then you can run it with nohup.

Be advised that yu will need to start it again if you reboot.

here is the [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)